# Extract unique ip and date form log file, than sort them by date

Tags: python-3.x

I need someone help. There is a database output log file with some fields. It is necessary to extract only the fields with ip addresses (#1100:") and dates("#907:").
    After that I need to remove a doublet addresses and sort them by date. I could not do it.

```
ip = []
date = [] 
uniq_ip = {}

file2 = open("list_of_ip.txt", "w")
file3 = open("uniq_ip.txt", "w")

# opening and reading log file
# adding ip and date to lists
with open("db_output.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.split()
        if line[0] == '#1100:':
            ip.append(line[1])
            file2.write(line[1] + "-")

        if line[0] == '#907:':
            date.append(int(line[1]))
            file2.write(line[1] + "\n")

# opening and file with ip and dates (dates like strings, not date object)  log file
# adding ip and date to lists

with open("list_of_ip.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        ip = line.split("-")[0]
        date = line.split("-")[1]
        uniq_ip[ip] = date

# try sorting a dict by value
    sorted_by_value = sorted(uniq_ip.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1])
    for elem in sorted_by_value:
        file3.write(elem[0] + " - " + elem[1])
```

I did something, but it doesn't work, can't sort.
Thanks.